# cassandra spring boot primary key column

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I have a cassandra table with primary key column “id”. I need to add list of students with “first_name”, “last_name”, and “age” fields. 
How can i add student list to table, where “id” column should be filled automatically with auto incremented value starting from 1?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your entity class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
private Long id;
```

Spring Boot will automatically increment the id. There are other ways to automatically change the value. The value of strategy can be AUTO, TABLE, SEQUENCE, or IDENTITY.

I would recommend using the SEQUENCE GENERATOR

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers

Comment: The question about Cassandra and you must specific/initialize the ID value, Spring has nothing to do with it.